# Is it possible to determine proxy based comments?

Tags: spam

I think proxy based comments mostly spam. So what is the best way of determining proxy using comments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but it's unlikely that you succeed for comment spammers (and how do you separate them from legitimate proxy users?):

```
$proxy = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

Comment: well i think it is better to keep all of them away. thanks for answer.